# How to list all installed/activated Apache modules on a server

Tags: server, apache2

To (roughly) check for the [CVE-2014-6271 vulnerability](https://blogs.akamai.com/2014/09/environment-bashing.html) and to have better general insight.

I want to check if a server uses `mod_cgi` or `mod_cgid` modules

How do I list all installed / activated Apache modules on a running Ubuntu Apache HTTP server?

I can use this:

```
apache2ctl -l
```

but that shows only the compiled-in modules.

Comment: And FYI the enabled modules can be found listed as symlinks in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` - `a2enmod` and `a2dismod` are helper commands to manage the enabled modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apache2ctl -M
```

will do the job and it's equivalent with:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

You can see also `apache2ctl -h`.